# Is there any way to hide columns controls button in Magento2 admin UI component for specific user role

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent

I have to hide "Columns" control button for specific user roles in admin UI grid. Looks like it's managed through xml `<columnsControls name="columns_controls">`. I tried to manage via meta but it seems UI grid not able to manage via PHP meta.

Is there any way to hide & show "Columns" control button in UI admin grid please suggest / guide me.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution

1. add custom PHP class to `listingToolbar`

   XML Code

[image]

2. Create PHP class  `<COMPANY><MODULE>\Component\ManageControl">'` and extend to `Magento\Ui\Component\Container`

[image]

3. Add `prepare` function and un set component which you don't want to show to specific user roles

I hope it will help for others.

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit tricky, but i hope this way can help you

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Container">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Ui_Component_Listing_ColumnsControlsPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Ui\Component\Listing\ColumnsControlsPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Ui/Component/Listing/ColumnsControlsPlugin.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Ui\Component\Listing;

class ColumnsControlsPlugin
{
    public function beforePrepare(\Magento\Ui\Component\Container $subject): array
    {
        $listingName = $subject->getContext()->getNamespace();
        $component   = $subject->getName();

        // example restrict columns_controls for sales_order_grid
        if ($listingName === 'sales_order_grid' && $component === 'columns_controls') {
            $config = $subject->getConfiguration();
            $config['displayArea'] = false;
            $subject->setData('config', $config);
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Victor, thank you for your help & time. by the way I have found some alternative.